# Why state update one click after with flat list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

to simplify the question: I have Three states

1. **massageType** - user chose type of massage.
2. **avHoursInDay** - to check all the available hours in the day that clicked.
3. **avHoursByType** - to manipulate the array of **avHoursInDay** and change the hours depend on the "massageType" that the user chose.(because the massageType have different lengths so hours that available depend on the massageType).

**THE QUESTION:** why my state change one click late.(example in the end)

**function 1 - to handle with the hours available:**

```
    const handleDay = day => {
    setSelectedDay(day);
    const dayMeetings = weekMeetings.filter(meet => meet.startDate.split("T")[0] === day.dateString);
    let availableHours = hours.map(e => ({ ...e }));
    for (let i = 0; i < dayMeetings.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < hours.length; j++) {
            if (moment(dayMeetings[i].startDate).format("LT") === hours[j].time) {
                availableHours[j].busy = true;
                availableHours[j + 1].busy = true;
                if (dayMeetings[i].massageType === "sweden" || dayMeetings[i].massageType==="fullbody" ) {
                    availableHours[j + 2].busy = true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    setAvHoursInDay(availableHours);
    setAvHoursByType([]);
    if (massageType.key !== -1) massageTypeHandler(massageType);

};
```

**function 2 - to manipulate the hours available depend on massage type:**

```
    const massageTypeHandler = item => {
    setMassageType(item);
    let mapDateByType = avHoursInDay.map(e => ({ ...e }));
    for (let i = 0; i < avHoursInDay.length; i++) {
        if ((i === avHoursInDay.length - 3 && avHoursInDay[i].busy === false && item.key === 2) || item.key === 3) {
            mapDateByType[i].busy = true;
        }
        if (i === avHoursInDay.length - 1 || i === avHoursInDay.length - 2) {
            mapDateByType[i].busy = true;
        } else if (avHoursInDay[i].busy === false) {
            if (avHoursInDay[i + 1].busy === true) {
                mapDateByType[i].busy = true;
            } else if ((item.key === 2 || item.key === 3) && avHoursInDay[i + 2].busy === true) {
                mapDateByType[i].busy = true;
            }
        }
    }
    setAvHoursByType(mapDateByType);
};
```

=======================

now i have flatList that when user clicked its go to function 2:

```
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <StyledButton
                        key={item.key}
                        onPress={() => massageTypeHandler(item)}
                        buttonStyle={
                            item.key === massageType.key
                                ? [styles.massagetypebutton, styles.selectedbutton]
                                : styles.massagetypebutton
                        }
                        text={item.massageType}
                    />
                )}
                keyExtractor={item => item.key.toString()}
            />
```

and calendar that go to function 1 (that invoke function 2 also):

```
<Calendar
            minDate={new Date()}
            markedDates={{
                [selectedDay.dateString]: {
                    selected: true,
                    disableTouchEvent: true,
                },
            }}
            theme={calendarTheme}
            onDayPress={handleDay}
            style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
        />
        {selectedDay && (
            <Text style={styles.daytitle}>יום {moment(selectedDay.dateString).format("dddd  DD/MM/YYYY")}</Text>
        )}
        <AvailableHours avHoursInDay={avHoursByType} />
```

**the question in extend:**
everything worked correctly and state change to the right available places.
**but** every render change only one click after .
for exmaple:

- first I click date 7 - > gave me empty array,
- click date 8 -> gave me the available of date 7
- click date 15-> gave me availables of date 8

something updated in late..

help please , thanks in advance,

- in the image u can see Im on date 10 and the availables places its
  from date 8 (which clicked before 10), next click I will get
  availables of date 10.

[image: image for demonstration:]

(I would be very happy if you could give me a code review if you see a faster way than two such long functions)

Comment: A bit difficult to follow what your code is doing, could you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example and maybe a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue? This usually occurs when you attempt to access an enqueued state update, i.e. ***you*** think it is the state from *next* render cycle but it is really still the state from the *current* render cycle.

Comment: So after checking I realized that the problem is that probably the first function that take charge of "setAvHoursInDay" is not enough to change when it comes to the second function. Is there a way to change the state of "setAvHoursInDay" before the render?

Answer (score 1):

[lift-state-up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and use `useReducer` in order to manipulate multiple states fields simultaneously.

```
function FooCalendar() {
  const [state, action] = useReducer(
      /* your initial state & implementation, move your BL logic to the reducer */
      )  
    // pass the state to your components
    const { selectedDay, avHoursByType } = state;
  return (
    <>
      <Calendar
        minDate={new Date()}
        markedDates={{
          [selectedDay.dateString]: {
            selected: true,
            disableTouchEvent: true,
          },
        }}
        theme={calendarTheme}
        onDayPress={(day) => {
            action({payload: {day}, type: 'DATE_CHANGED' })}
        }
        style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
      />
      {selectedDay && (
        <Text style={styles.daytitle}>
          יום {moment(selectedDay.dateString).format('dddd  DD/MM/YYYY')}
        </Text>
      )}
      <AvailableHours avHoursInDay={avHoursByType} onMessageTypeChanged={(item) => {
        action({payload: {item}, type: 'MESSAGE_TYPE_CHANGED' })
      }} />
    </>
  );
}
```